# Como liberar memória de um malloc() interno a uma função que retorna um ponteiro?

Tags: c, ponteiro, gerenciamento-de-memória

Como liberar um `malloc()` interno a uma função que retorna um ponteiro? De uma forma simples de tentar exemplificar minha dúvida, considere a seguinte função `f()`:

```
int *f(int tam)
{
    int *ptr = malloc(tam * sizeof *ptr);

    return ptr;
}
```

Que utiliza alocação dinâmica de memória dentro da função e retorna o ponteiro alocado. Estou utilizando, em uma função (como `main()`) da forma:

```
int main(void)
{
    int tamanho = 5;

    int *ponteiro;

    ponteiro = f(tamanho);

    if(ponteiro != NULL)
    {
        free(ponteiro);
    }
    else
        puts("Memória insuficiente.");      

    return 0;
}
```

Onde `ponteiro` recebe o retorno da função `f()`. Seria esse responsável por checar se há memória disponível e dar `free()` no `malloc()` da função como está descrito acima em `main()`?

Caso seja, em funções compostas em chamada, também seria feito dessa forma? O exemplo abaixo mostra duas funções: uma chamando a outra,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

int *f(int tam)
{
    int *ptr = malloc(tam * sizeof *ptr);

    return ptr;
}

int *g(int *ptr)
{
    return ptr;
}

int main(void)
{
    int tamanho = 5;

    int *ponteiro;

    ponteiro = g(f(tamanho));

    if(ponteiro != NULL)
    {
        free(ponteiro);
    }
    else
        puts("Memória insuficiente.");      

     return 0;
}
```

Seria o ponteiro que recebe o retorno "final" responsável pela alocação dinâmica do `malloc()`? E assim indefinidamente para funções desse tipo compostas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A regra básica é **não faça isso**. Mas se fizer o caminho é este que você apresentou, não tem muito o que inventar. Ou seja, se você não vai seguir uma regra de organização que todos estabelecem como a mais clara, crie então sua regra e assuma o risco.

O ideal é deixar sempre a função responsável por alocar memória ser a responsável por liberá-la, raramente você tem alguma vantagem em fazer diferente. De uma maneira geral a filosofia das funções em C que precisam de uma memória alocada que pode existir além da sua duração é sempre receber um ponteiro para a memória previamente alocada por outro código. É raro, e normalmente considerado errado, alocar memória e retornar isto para uso externo à função criadora.

O motivo para esta "regra" é justamente não tornar ainda mais difícil acompanhar o tempo de vida de um objeto. É muito fácil não só cometer erros mas criar situações potencialmente perigosas. Pode até parecer simples em um exemplo contido assim, mas em um código real fica bem complicado saber se você deve liberar a memória e se ela ainda não foi liberada.

Quem aloca a memória deve ser responsável por todo tratamento necessário. Se não fizer isto se prepare para arcar com um gerenciamento complicado desnecessariamente.

Seguindo algumas regras, gerenciamento de memória dinâmica em C não é tão difícil assim. Claro, você ainda pode se esquecer do que fazer, você pode cometer erros, se confundir, mas seguindo uma boa organização você não se perde facilmente como algumas pessoas imaginam.

O exemplo é bem ruim para demonstrar qualquer coisa realmente útil mas só para mostrar o jeito mais correto de fazer algo semelhante:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

int *f(int *ptr) {
    //faz alguma coisa com ptr aqui
    //do jeito que estava aqui, uma chamada do jeito errado criaria confusão
    //ainda não está ideal mas o exemplo todo não está
    return ptr;
}

void g(int *ptr) {
    //faz alguma coisa com ptr aqui
    return;
}

int main(void) {
    int tamanho = 5;
    //o importante é que o malloc agora está próximo do free, fica mais fácil acompanhar
    int *ponteiro = malloc(tamanho * sizeof *ponteiro); 

    g(f(ponteiro));

    if(ponteiro != NULL) { //só isto não garante nada em um exemplo mais completo
        free(ponteiro); //não é difícil associar este free ao malloc logo acima
    } else {
        puts("Memória insuficiente.");      
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/MallocDoneRight.c).

Não pegue uma solução e procure um problema para aplicá-la. Ache a melhor solução para um problema que você tem.

Eu só conheço três motivos para tratar a liberação em outro lugar:

1. querer artificialmente diminuir um código em um lugar (não quer dizer que é uma boa coisa);
2. ter uma função de gerenciamento de memória que auxilie o trabalho (poucas pessoas sabem fazer isto certo);
3. está usando algo ruim criado por terceiros e portanto você não tem controle para arrumar isto.

Em geral APIs em C exigem que o consumidor seja responsável por alocar a memória, é raro entregar uma memória alocada pela API usada.

Mesmo que pareça certo em um exemplo simples pode ser uma má ideia em exemplos mais complexos.

C é uma linguagem onde o gerenciamento deve ser feito manualmente e precisa muito cuidado, se estes cuidados forem tomados nem é tão difícil. Se preferir um gerenciamento mais automático opte por C++ ou uma linguagem com *garbage collector*.

Comment: Infelizmente foi preciso, pois tive que retornar um array e daí surgiu a dúvida.

Comment: Se você tivesse postado um exemplo real, talvez eu pudesse te mostrar como fazer de outra forma. Eu só conheço três motivos para tratar a liberação em outro lugar: 1) querer artificialmente diminuir um código em um lugar (não quer dizer que é uma boa coisa); 2) ter uma função de gerenciamento de memória que auxilie o trabalho (poucas pessoas sabem fazer isto certo); 3) está usando algo criado por terceiros e portanto você não tem controle para arrumar isto.

Comment: Poderia ser assim. O que você fez está correto dentro deste contexto errado :) O que posso dizer sobe o uso do `free()`? Ele está correto mas depende do contexto exato. Neste exemplo eu sei que funciona, mas se você mudar alguma vírgula pode ser que isto não seja suficiente mais. Eu só posso dizer o que está correto em situação real. Se você quiser as coisas mais automáticas procure outra linguagem como o C++ ou outra mais automática ainda.

Comment: Ok. Vi a resposta refeita, por isso apaguei o comentário. Vou começar a estudar C++ também. Grato pela resposta. Na verdade fiquei em dúvida somente pela possibilidade do código ser executado assim, e se poderia ser melhor interpretado, mas na implementação vou ficar com sua opção.

Comment: Excelente resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Contudo, caso a alocação que você vá fazer necessite de um pouco mais de desempenho e a própria função que está alocando a memória será a mesma a desalocar, se esse tamanho não for `__libc_use_alloca(size)` (no caso do GCC), usar a função `alloca();` se encaixaria melhor na situação já que ela ganha em desempenho por não usar o heap e ela mesma já desaloca a memória alocada sem a necessidade de usar o `free();` evitando o *memory leaking*. Se não é o caso, e então, nesse sentido, desempenho não é uma prioridade nesse momento, considere usar o `calloc();` visto que ele aloca e inicializa o espaço alocado com zeros.

=-D