# Retornando string de função direto e com array

Tags: c, array, string, funções, return

O que dá certo:

```
void *teste();

int main () {
    printf("\nRESULTADO: %s\n", teste());
    return 0;
}

void *teste(){
    return "Ponteiro";
}
```

O que dá errado:

```
void *teste();

int main () {
    printf("\nRESULTADO: %s\n", teste());
    return 0;
}

void *teste(){
    char p[10]="Ponteiro";
    return p;
}
```

Por que a primeira da certo e a segunda não?
Como retorno uma string alocada em uma variável?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O primeiro está retornando um ponteiro para uma área estática do código que sempre está disponível. O texto já existe dentro do executável.

O segundo está retornando um ponteiro para uma área da pilha, que pode ou não estar disponível quando a função termina. No termino dela há um desempilhamento, então todo o conteúdo que estava na pilha quando a função estava executando não pode mais ser acessada, então uma tentativa de acessar essa área é um erro (ainda que por coincidência possa ser possível se o dado ainda não foi apagado, mas não deve confiar nisso, nunca).

Note que mesmo no segundo exemplo existe o texto na área estática para jogar na variável `p`. Quando executa a linha ali o conteúdo da área estática é copiada para a *stack* e `p` tem o endereço dessa área e não da estática.

*Arrays* são tipos por valor e portanto o seu valor fica na área de armazenamento onde foi declarado. A variável local é o local de armazenamento dele.

Só pode acessar um objeto fora de uma função onde ele foi criado se estiver na área estática já presente no código ou no *heap*, onde você é responsável pelo [tempo de vida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) do objeto.

Entenda [O que são e onde estão a "stack" e "heap"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101).

Quando tem que receber um texto que vem de uma função o correto é alocar a memória na função que vai usar e passar o endereço deste local alocado para a função que irá gerar o texto, assim esta função tem toda a responsabilidade de alocar e liberar a memória. Sempre deve fazer assim. Toda filosofia do C é em cima disso.

Tem quem acha que muito código e a alocação deveria ir na função que gera o texto, mas isso não é adequado. Funciona em sistemas simples, mas começar fazer coisas maiores é muito risco ter que gerenciar a alocação e a liberação em lugares diferentes.

Se for usar o texto só ali e ele for garantido que ele não é absurdamente grande pode alocar na *stack*. Então é só declarar o *array* e não precisa liberar porque o que está no *stack* é gerenciado automaticamente.

Mas tem um problema, isso exige que faça uma cópia do texto. Se é pequeno tudo bem, se é grande não é eficiente. A solução dada na outra resposta não funciona em todas situações e tem compilador que sequer compila.

Então quase sempre a solução é alocar no *heap*.

Fiz um exemplo do jeito errado que é alocar a memória no *heap* dentro da função que gera o texto e deixei quem chamar essa função se preocupar com a liberação. Mas isso dá margem para a pessoa esquecer de fazer ou fazer na hora errada, criando sérios problemas. Você é responsável por gerenciar o tempo de vida do objeto no *heap*. Então é melhor sempre fazer par de `malloc()` e `free()`.

Como a alocação dinâmica no *heap* pode falhar tem que verificar se deu certo antes de fazer qualquer coisa nesta posição de memória.

Copiei também porque para funcionar em qualquer situação. Então nesse caso também não é eficiente.

Então qual é a solução? O primeiro exemplo da pergunta é a melhor forma na maioria dos casos, porque ele só pega o texto que já está em área estática de forma eficiente. Só vai dar problema se precisa mudar este valor. Não pode mexer na área estática, aí só copiando mesmo. Na maioria das vezes não precisa mexer.

Eu só mudaria o tipo de retorna para `char *`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void teste(char texto[10]) {
    strcpy(texto, "Ponteiro"); //isto não é seguro, mas sabemos que funciona neste caso
}

char *teste2() {
    char *texto = malloc(10);
    if (texto != NULL) strcpy(texto, "Ponteiro"); //neste caso dá para eliminar isto, deixei porque o normal é fazer assim
    return texto;
}

int main () {
    char texto[10];
    teste(texto);
    printf("\nRESULTADO: %s\n", texto);
    //segunda forma não recomendada
    char *texto2 = teste2();
    if (texto2 != NULL) {
        printf("\nRESULTADO: %s\n", texto2);
        free(texto2); //tem que librar a memória que foi alocada por outra função
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/R37zSH). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ukrkzzqg-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/ReturnText.c).

Veja mais em:

- [Como liberar memória de um malloc interno a uma função que retorna um ponteiro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51613/101)
- [Ponteiro de string não funciona como o esperado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/160692/101)
- [char[] ou *char malloc?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141975/101)

Comment: Então, como eu faria pra retornar uma string alocada em uma variável?

Comment: Você não pode a não ser por cópia, o que não é eficiente. Então tem que alocar em outro lugar que não a variável, conforme eu coloquei na resposta. Editei para colocar novos *links*. Essa questão de como fazer já foi respondida antes em outras perguntas.

Answer (score 4):

> Por que a primeira da certo e a segunda não?

A primeira dá certo pois quando o seu programa é executado ele primeiramente aloca um espaço para essa **string constante**, e armazena esse valor nesse espaço. Assim quando é executado `return "Ponteiro";` ele já sabe o endereço dessa **string constante** e retorna esse endereço.

A segunda não dá certo, pois quando a função `void *teste()` termina de executar, o que foi alocado dentro de seu escopo é desalocado (com exceção do que for alocado na *heap* - `malloc`/`calloc`).

---

> Como retorno uma string alocada em uma variável?

Vou dar dois exemplos de como fazer isso, primeiro a *stack* e a outro usando a *heap* (`malloc`/`calloc`)

## Usando a *Stack*

```
void *teste(char *p);

int main () {
    char p[10];
    printf("\nRESULTADO: %s\n", teste(&p));
    return 0;
}

void *teste(char *p){
    p ="Ponteiro";
    return p;
}
```

É garantido que isso irá funcionar, pois `char p[10];` só irá ser desalocado quando a `main()` terminar, ou seja, já terei feito tudo o que eu queria com a variável antes dela ser desalocada.

## Usando a *Heap*

```
void *teste(char *p);

int main () {
    char *p = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*10);

    if(p == NULL) {
        printf("Não foi possivel alocar 10bytes para o array p");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("\nRESULTADO: %s\n", teste(p));
    free(p);
    return 0;
}

void *teste(char *p){
    p ="Ponteiro";
    return p;
}
```

Perceba que qualquer função um pode alocar e desalocar usando `malloc`/`free`, de forma que você consegue fazer sua variável viver por mais tempo que o fim de uma função *X* qualquer.