# Qual a diferença entre a função "malloc()" e uma variável criada?

Tags: c, variáveis, memória, malloc

Eu estava lendo alguns códigos em C e eu percebi que para gerar algum objeto em específico é usada a função `malloc()`. Não é mais fácil criar este objeto em uma variável do que usar a `malloc()`?

Aqui vai um exemplo:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint32_t idade;
} Pessoa;

void main()
{
    // Geralmente eu vejo isto:
    Pessoa *p = (Pessoa *)malloc(sizeof(Pessoa));
    // ... (usa a struct pessoa)


    // Mas não é mais fácil fazer isto?:
    Pessoa p;
    // ... (usa a struct pessoa)
}
```

Por que o `malloc()` é geralmente usado para alocar memória se eu posso criar a variável do objeto, como é o `Pessoa p;`? E tem diferenças entre estes dois jeitos de alocar memória? Se sim, quais?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para criar um objeto não é necessário chamar `malloc()`, até porque ela é feita para alocar memória dinâmica, só isso. Ela aloca a memória e devolve um endereço onde houve a alocação. Criar e colocar um objeto lá é outra operação separada, em geral será feita com o operador de atribuição (`=`) ou uma função que faça o mesmo.

O comentário que diz usar a estrutura `Pessoa` está equivocado, porque não há um objeto ali, pelo menos não um inicializado, então só tem lixo, você poderá até acessar aquele local como se tivesse, mas na prática estará coletando lixo.

Inclusive [não faz sentido fazer o *cast* na função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/285379/101).

É mais fácil fazer a segunda opção, se é o que deseja. Se quer alocar na memória automática é bem mais fácil, inclusive porque depois não terá que [liberar a alocação feita com `malloc()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43766/101). Mas essa alocação só está disponível para essa função, não permite que o objeto sobreviva ao fim da função, nem que possa ser usado em outros locais. Em muitos casos basta isso, em outros não, a alocação dinâmica é necessária quando não se sabe quanto tempo ela deve sobreviver ou se sabe que é além do limite de onde ela foi criada. Em alguns casos o tamanho pode ser o determinante. Mas isso pode ser visto abaixo.

Pode ler mais em:

- [Quando alocar memória dinamicamente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/291965/101)
- [Variáveis declaradas dentro de blocos ou subprogramas são alocadas dinamicamente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/280973/101)
- [Usar variáveis estáticas ou dinâmicas em meus códigos? O que seria mais eficiente ou melhor visto no mercado de trabalho?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/342463/101)
- [Alocação dinâmica de memória X vetor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120103/101)
- [Performance de acesso a dados na heap e stack e alocação de objetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56580/101)
- [Retornando string de função direto e com array](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/252163/101)

E também pode pesquisar mais sobre o assunto aqui no site, tem muita informação útil. Já tem alguns *links* disponíveis aí nas perguntas *linkadas*. O pessoal perdeu um pouco isso de aprender com as respostas daqui. Azar.

A pergunta mudou enquanto eu respondia.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Então quer dizer que se eu quiser que uma variável fique por tempo indeterminado na memória, é só alocar ela com o "malloc()"? E eu vejo muito código por aí em C que aloca uma struct usando o "malloc()" e depois inicializa as variáveis dela usando o operador "->", e como as variáveis de uma struct são inicializadas se são "lixo", como você disse?

Comment: Quando inicializa deixa de ser lixo.

Comment: Então na teoria não faz diferença usar "malloc()" ou não pra alocar qualquer coisa? [Nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/285379/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-nas-sintaxe-ptr-int-malloc-sizeofint-e-ptr-malloc-s) que você colocou, a pessoa usa "malloc()" para alocar um ponteiro para um int, não é mais fácil só escrever o "int *ptr;"? Então deve-se só usar o "malloc()" em alocação dinâmica? Como alocar um array de x posições?

Comment: Não, se fizer não está alocando memória. Tem que ler todo material e até mais porque vai puxando um fio e vai entrando em outro assunto.

Comment: Ok, irei ler, obrigado de qualquer forma